# ValidatorError: path: username required, path: email required, path: password required,

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I’m getting a validation error need to find a path required,
this exact method of uploading to database is working for me perfectly for another form on the website

//this is the html ( ejs )

```
<div className="sign-in-area">
    <form action="/signin" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div>
        <label for="userName">UserName:</label>
        <input type="text" id="userName" name="username" required/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="email">Enter Email</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required/>
      </div>
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

then this is the mongoose user schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const blogSchemaUser = new Schema({

username: {
 type: String,
 required: true,
},
email: {
 type: String,
 required: true
},
password: {
 type: String,
 required: true
},

}, { timestamps: true });

const User = mongoose.model('user',blogSchemaUser);
module.exports = User;
```

the server connection to mongodb

```
const app = express();

// middleware & static files
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// connect to mongodb & listen for requests
const dbURL =
```

"mongodb+srv://myusernameandpassword@samstam.hte26or.mongodb.net/cookingSite";

```
mongoose.connect(dbURL, { useNewUrlParser: true, 
useUnifiedTopology: true })
```

.then(result => app.listen(8080))
.catch(err => console.log(err));

and the route of the signin

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const User = require('../models/user');


router.get('/signin', (req, res) => {
res.render('signin', { title: 'Create a new blog' 
})
})

router.post('/signin', (req, res) => {

const user = new User({
  username: req.body.username,
  email: req.body.email,
  passcode: req.body.password
}); 

    user.save()
   .then(result => {
    res.redirect('/');
    console.log(user)
   })
   .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
   });
```

});

the error

Error: user validation failed: username: Path `username` is required., email: Path `email` is required., passcode: Path `passcode` is required.
at ValidationError.inspect (/Users/samraitan/Documents/GitHub/website-food/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validation.js:50:26)
at formatValue (node:internal/util/inspect:782:19)
at inspect (node:internal/util/inspect:347:10)
at formatWithOptionsInternal (node:internal/util/inspect:2167:40)
at formatWithOptions (node:internal/util/inspect:2029:10)
at console.value (node:internal/console/constructor:324:14)
at console.log (node:internal/console/constructor:360:61)
at /Users/samraitan/Documents/GitHub/website-food/routes/userRoutes.js:24:17
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
errors: {
username: ValidatorError: Path `username` is required.
at validate (/Users/samraitan/Documents/GitHub/website-food/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1346:13)
at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (/Users/samraitan/Documents/GitHub/website-food/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1330:7)
at /Users/samraitan/Documents/GitHub/website-food/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2877:18
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11) {
properties: [Object],
kind: 'required',
path: 'username',
value: undefined,
reason: undefined,
[Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
},
email: ValidatorError: Path `email` is required.
at validate (/Users/samraitan/Documents/GitHub/website-food/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1346:13)
at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (/Users/samraitan/Documents/GitHub/website-food/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1330:7)
at /Users/samraitan/Documents/GitHub/website-food/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2877:18
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11) {
properties: [Object],
kind: 'required',
path: 'email',
value: undefined,
reason: undefined,
[Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
},
passcode: ValidatorError: Path `passcode` is required.
at validate (/Users/samraitan/Documents/GitHub/website-food/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1346:13)
at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (/Users/samraitan/Documents/GitHub/website-food/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1330:7)
at /Users/samraitan/Documents/GitHub/website-food/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2877:18
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11) {
properties: [Object],
kind: 'required',
path: 'passcode',
value: undefined,
reason: undefined,
[Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
}
},
_message: 'user validation failed'
}
^C
samraitan@SRs-MacBook-Pro website-food % node app2
/Users/samraitan/Documents/GitHub/website-food/app2.js:71
router.post('/postss', (req, res) => {
^

ReferenceError: router is not defined
at Object. (/Users/samraitan/Documents/GitHub/website-food/app2.js:71:1)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
samraitan@SRs-MacBook-Pro website-food % node app2
Error: user validation failed: image: Path `image` is required., body: Path `body` is required., title: Path `title` is required.
at ValidationError.inspect (/Users/samraitan/Documents/GitHub/website-food/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validation.js:50:26)
at formatValue (node:internal/util/inspect:782:19)
at inspect (node:internal/util/inspect:347:10)
at formatWithOptionsInternal (node:internal/util/inspect:2167:40)
at formatWithOptions (node:internal/util/inspect:2029:10)
at console.value (node:internal/console/constructor:324:14)
at console.log (node:internal/console/constructor:360:61)
at /Users/samraitan/Documents/GitHub/website-food/routes/userRoutes.js:24:17
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
errors: {
image: ValidatorError: Path `image` is required.
at validate (/Users/samraitan/Documents/GitHub/website-food/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1346:13)
at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (/Users/samraitan/Documents/GitHub/website-food/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1330:7)
at /Users/samraitan/Documents/GitHub/website-food/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2877:18
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11) {
properties: [Object],
kind: 'required',
path: 'image',
value: undefined,
reason: undefined,
[Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
},
body: ValidatorError: Path `body` is required.
at validate (/Users/samraitan/Documents/GitHub/website-food/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1346:13)
at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (/Users/samraitan/Documents/GitHub/website-food/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1330:7)
at /Users/samraitan/Documents/GitHub/website-food/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2877:18
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11) {
properties: [Object],
kind: 'required',
path: 'body',
value: undefined,
reason: undefined,
[Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
},
title: ValidatorError: Path `title` is required.
at validate (/Users/samraitan/Documents/GitHub/website-food/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1346:13)
at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (/Users/samraitan/Documents/GitHub/website-food/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1330:7)
at /Users/samraitan/Documents/GitHub/website-food/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2877:18
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11) {
properties: [Object],
kind: 'required',
path: 'title',
value: undefined,
reason: undefined,
[Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
}
},
_message: 'user validation failed'
}

Comment: can you add the errors?

Comment: Try logging the content of `user` saving it.

Comment: I did but I get the error that I wrote I get a error for every one of the variables that mongoose is supposed to get error for the path

Answer (score 0):

try to console.log your input values like (username.value), I am sure the error should be in main script file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).